# Windows Subsystem Linux terminal scrolling using keyboard

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently using WSL for some shared development and one thing is bothering me: how to scroll terminal up/down in classical UNIX termianl fashion (i.e. using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd>)? It does not work with any of common combinations:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>

With or without `Shortcuts with Ctrl enabled` option.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you left click on the window and press Shift + PgUp it should work. This will make your cursor select everything in its path and it will look super ugly, but atleast it works. I would stick to using the scroll wheel for now.

Comment: In PowerShell PageUp and PageDown scrolls up and down the console. Unfortunately running bash inside powershell still doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let have some little introduction. In Windows, [Command Prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) is a shell, not a terminal. And `wsl.exe` is a command line program. There are many [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators) with Unix-like terminal features for Windows.

For shared environment, using [ssh with WSL](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+with+wsl) (Windows Subsystem for Linux) is better option. Run `sshd` daemon in WSL with `sudo service ssh start` command (Here I skip the certificate exchange step). There are many [articles and Q&A](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+with+wsl) you can follow. Now the main part i.e. keyboard shortcuts. In Windows side, run `ssh user_name@localhost` with [any terminal](https://alternativeto.net/browse/search?q=terminal+emulators) emulator like [putty](https://www.putty.org/), [mintty](https://github.com/mintty/mintty), kitty, MobaXterm, ConEmu etc., all have that page up/down keyboard shortcuts built-in.

If you want to skip the hassle of ssh setup then you can use [wsltty](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty), which uses [mintty](https://github.com/mintty/mintty) (terminal emulator) and [wslbridge](https://github.com/rprichard/wslbridge) (same as ssh but pre-configured). mintty has [the keyboard shortcuts](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html) like previous examples.

Comment: This is full and reach in technical knowledge answer to my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Mouse scroll works fine, but not the keyboard.

I suggest using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) with the following script
to enable <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd>:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass

+PgUp::
Send {WheelUp}
Return

+PgDn::
Send {WheelDown}
Return

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: This works well, though I prefered to use multiple instances of `{WheelUp}` and `{WheelDown}` to scroll more than the few lines it does by default.  e.g. `Send {WheelUp}{WheelUp}{WheelUp}{WheelUp}`

Comment: The `return` are redundant extra lines (since only a single command is in each hotkey), but good idea, I've added it to my AHK library.
`#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
+PgUp:: Send {WheelUp}
+PgDn:: Send {WheelDown}
#IfWinActive`. However, how can we extend this to also work for Windows Terminal; do you know the class for that application when using Linux under Windows Terminal?

Comment: @YorSubs: Windows Terminal is detected as `ahk_class CASCADIA_HOSTING_WINDOW_CLASS` or `ahk_exe WindowsTerminal.exe`. You may find this by right-click on the AHK icon and selecting "Window Spy", then clicking Windows Terminal.

Comment: @YorSubs as written, the `return` are absolutely NOT redundant. they are necessary unless you write the Send command on the same line as the hotkey, directly after the `::`

Comment: Sorry @mikew, indeed, good point. I guess for myself I mostly always condense one line hotkeys on the same line since this would be quite tidy, but yeah, you were illustrating long form and the `return`'s are absolutely required in the way you say.

Comment: Note: For some reason, the one-line version of the script did not work for me, but it worked after I formulated it as above. I don't know if it's a bug in AutoHotkey or an unpublished "feature".

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with [Biswapriyo](https://superuser.com/a/1408930/1017330). The [Windows 10 Terminal (Preview)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n8g5rfz9xk3?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) is awesome and using it with VSCode is a pleasure. For instance, it automatically notices when you called `code` in WSL and starts your Windows VSCode with the Remote Extension—very seamless.

Scrolling is possible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUP</kbd>. Using both these modifiers seems to be [the theme](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings) here.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/). From PowerShell I can SSH into my virtual machines and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>UP/DOWN</kbd> (arrow keys) to scroll up or down, out of the box. Also works with WSL machines.

Answer (score 0):

I found the better way to resolve this I have installed windows-terminal from microsoft and then changed the properties of those with my custom.

Windows terminal is way better than existing powersell or cmd prompt so what we can do is

- Install widnows terminal from microsoft store (easiest way)
- you can completly custmize the windows terminal. with this document :- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions
- so basically i have added the below items in the file

```
{ "command": "scrollUp", "keys": "shift+pageup" },
{ "command": "scrollDown", "keys": "shift+pagedowndown" },
```

- And issue resolved, And also this allow too much customization :)